# A correct query produces a syntax error when used as a sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

First, I have this query, which works just fine:

```
DELETE FROM notifications
WHERE data @> '{"postID": 321}'
RETURNING user_id, read
```

But then, I use it as a sub-query:

```
SELECT d.user_id, count(d.user_id)
FROM (
    DELETE FROM notifications
    WHERE data @> '{"postID": 321}'
    RETURNING user_id, read
) as d
WHERE d.read = false
GROUP BY d.user_id
```

And get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 16:  DELETE FROM notifications
                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 245
```

1. How do I fix this and achieve the intended result?
2. How, in general, can a correct query become an incorrect sub-query?

Comment: "*How, in general, can a correct query become an incorrect sub-query?*" because not every query can be used as a sub-query, and `DELETE` statements fall into that category. Same for e.g. `TRUNCATE` or `create table`

Comment: Can you please point me the documentation that explains this difference in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH d as (
      DELETE FROM notifications
      WHERE data @> '{"postID": 321}'
      RETURNING user_id, read
     ) 
SELECT d.user_id, count(d.user_id)
FROM d
WHERE d.read = false
GROUP BY d.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, that asnwers my first question. Can you explain further regarding my second?

Comment: @MaxYankov . . . Obviously a working query can fail as a subquery.  I think you have provided an example.

Comment: But why? Why does my example doesn't work and yours does?

Comment: @MaxYankov . . . Because the `delete` is allowed in a CTE but not a subquery.  This is a (convenient) Postgres extension, so the language can define it however the designers want.